# Is the group quotient well defined?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

If I want to quotient $V_{4}$ by $C_{2}$ then I've got three isomorphic copies of $C_{2}$ in $V_{4}$ to choose from, but whichever one I choose to quotient out by, I get $C_{2}$.

So I feel happy writing $V_{4} /  C_{2} = C_{2}$

But is that always the case?

Is there a group G with two isomorphic normal subgroups $H_{1}$, $H_{2}$ s.t. $G/H_{1} \ncong G/H_{2}$

Obviously they'll always have the same number of elements, but why would they have the same structure?

Comment: errr.., very probably!, I was trying to make it (not) work with Z2XZ4 earlier. I'll try again....

Comment: Yes it does, I am shame. I'd somehow convinced myself that if it broke it would break on 12 and completely missed 02.... Thank you! I leave it to wiser persons to decide whether to delete this and spare my blushes or leave it as a different way to ask the (now linked) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G=S_3\times\Bbb Z_3$. Note that if $H=\{e,(1\ \ 2\ \ 3),(1\ \ 3\ \ 2)\}\subset S_3$, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $S_3$ and $H\simeq\Bbb Z_3$. But $G/(H\times\{0\})\simeq\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$, whereas $G/(\{e\}\times\Bbb Z_3)\simeq S_3$.

Comment: Thank you, it seems examples are endless.... I couldn't break it or prove it in 2 hours of trying....